# What exactly does rewind job bookmark do in AWS Glue?

Tags: aws-glue

I have a Glue job that is executed every night. This job has failed for a couple of days so I thought I would re-run the job starting from the first day it failed.

Since there is a **Rewind job bookmark** option in the Glue console I used that to rewind to the time it first failed and then manually executed the job.

But when looking at the **Job run input** it looks like it processes files from a long time ago and not from the date when the jobs started failing.

How can this be? Did rewind actually reset the job bookmark to the beginning?

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/glue-troubleshooting-errors.html#error-job-bookmarks-reprocess-data maybe this can help you. Otherwise rewind should not set the bookmark to the beginning, only reset should.

Comment: In addition, if a job fails, there shouldn't be a bookmark.